# Connecting to socket.io server from c++ application

Tags: c++, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to do poc for my web based application, I have following

1) A basic node.js/socket.io based server on LINUX that serves basic web page as a client

**client.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     var socket = io.connect("169.xxx.xxx.xx:5000");

     socket.on("aServerEvent", function(data)
     {
       document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML = ("<hr/>" +
       data['message'] + document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML);
     });

     function sendMessage()
     {
        var msg = document.getElementById("message_input").value;
        socket.emit("aClientEvent", { message : msg});
     }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="message_input"/>
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">send</button>
    <div id="chatlog"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs')
    app.listen(5000,'169.xxx.xxx.xx');

function handler (req, res)
{
    fs.readFile("client.html", function (err, data)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading client.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

console.log('Server running at http://169.xxx.xxx.xx:5000/');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    socket.on('aClientEvent', function(data)
    {
        var newData = "serverResponse: " + data["message"].toUpperCase();
        io.sockets.emit("aServerEvent", { message: newData });
    });
});
```

So far so good, I input a text on the webpage(client) that gets read by server which returns upper case text as acknowledgment.

2) Now I want to write a basic C++ program on linux using websocketpp to establish a websocket based connection with my node.js/socket.io server

What is the best way to do that i.e how can I establish a websocket based connection between node.js server and c++ application (websocketpp based) ?

The closest matches I found are..

```
https://github.com/ebshimizu/socket.io-clientpp
```

(however uses rapidjson, I want to use libjson only)

```
https://github.com/uning/socket.io-client-cpp
```

(this looks like amended version of original websocketpp libraries and has lots of files in src which confuses me if all of them are required)

Any pointer would be much apreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Now socket.io has also C++ client. 
Look here https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp
There is also a blog post with complete chat example
http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/

Comment: When you're recommending a library, then you need to show how it can be applied in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running Linux there should be a package for this. I looked on Debian and websocketpp-dev would be what you need. Just try `yum search websocketpp` or `apt-get search websocketpp` and install the devel/dev package.
The doc can be found here: http://doxygen.websocketpp.org/annotated.html
I hope that was what you were looking for.